# Show line numbers of a file after "cut -d ";" -f3 |uniq -d"

Tags: text-processing, cut, uniq

I am trying to make a simple command that can show me the duplicate data from one specific column and also give me the original line number.

Example of file:

```
JENNIE;30;DOCTOR;F
SARA;26;POLICE;F
EDWARD;32;TEACHER;M
ROBERT;44;POLICE;M
```

With the following command I will get the duplicates from column 3

> cat FILE.txt |cut -d ";" -f3 |sort |uniq -d

The problem is that I need to get the original line number of the results.

My command shows:

```
POLICE
POLICE
```

And I want to get

```
2- POLICE
4- POLICE
```

Comment: is the dash/hypen an important part of your output, or would you be happy with "2 POLICE" etc?

Comment: Is that really the output you get?  I just get a single `POLICE`, and only if I sort first.

Comment: Umm... Your command outputs nothing as there are no consecutive lines that contain duplicated data in the 3rd column.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sort` and GNU `uniq`, you could do:

```
$ <FILE.txt awk -F';' '{print NR"- "$3}' | sort -st' ' -k2 | uniq -Df1
2- POLICE
4- POLICE
```

Lines are sorted first lexically on the text and then by number (`-s` preserves the original order for texts that sort the same). Add a `| sort -n` to sort by line number.

With `awk` alone:

```
awk -F';' '!x {c[$3]++}; x && c[$3] > 1 {print FNR"- "$3}' FILE.txt x=1 FILE.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that your current pipeline works in the way you claim but it does not with BSD or GNU tools.  Not sure if you are using something different.

I was able to come up with the following loop to to accomplish what you are asking:

```
for prof in $(cut -d\; -f3 FILE.txt | sort | uniq -d); do 
    awk -v pat="$prof" -F\; '$3 ~ pat{print NR"-",$3}' FILE.txt 
done
```

This will produce a list of professions that appear more than once and then use `awk` to find each occurance of them in the file, printing the line number and profession name.

awk will set the profession gathered from the `cut -d\; -f3 FILE.txt | sort | uniq -d` pipeline to the `pat` parameter and then search the file for lines containing that pattern in the 3rd field (using `;` as a field separator).  For lines that match it will print the line number and the 3rd field (separated by a dash).

Comment: Wow, thats amazing but Im a dummy with awk, im not sure how its works haha